# Unable to retrieve known keys in python/boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm attempting to connect to a coworkers S3 bucket using python and boto. I was previously able to do this without any issues, but they recently added prefixes/directories to the bucket and I can no longer access the keys.

Any attempts to get a key with bucket.get_key(keyname) return a NoneType. If I get all keys with bucket.get_all_keys(), I get a long list of keys.

```
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3()
>>> bucket = s3.get_bucket('bucket_name')
>>> keys=bucket.get_all_keys()
>>> len(keys)
1000
>>> keys[5:7]
[<Key: bucketname,/prod/keyname>, <Key: bucketname,/prod/keyname>]
>>> keys[6].get_contents_as_string()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1782, in get_contents_as_string
    response_headers=response_headers)
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1650, in get_contents_to_file
    response_headers=response_headers)
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1482, in get_file
    query_args=None)
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1514, in _get_file_internal
    override_num_retries=override_num_retries)
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 343, in open
    override_num_retries=override_num_retries)
  File "/home/myusername/.pyenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 303, in open_read
    self.resp.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.
```

I obscured some information, but they key names and prefixes take the form of /prod/word-123-123, where there are dashes and numbers in the names.

Is there any reason why this might be happening? Do I have to treat things differently now that there are prefixes/directories?

edit: I just got a coworker to add an item that has no prefix, and I was able to get it successfully.

```
>>> bucket.get_key('test-bucket-item')
<Key: bucketname,test-bucket-item>
>>> key=bucket.get_key('test-bucket-item')
>>> key.get_contents_as_string()
'test contents'
```

Comment: S3 object key including prefix.

Comment: /prod/ecommerce-1077229-1

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, S3 Object key is the whole things. It doesn't matter you create with "prefix"(AKA folder name) .  So this has nothing to do with the key.  Please check the bucket policies against your credentials.

Comment: Gotcha. I am able to access items that do not have a prefix in the same bucket. Another colleague of mine uses a php library to access the same bucket/keys with the same credentials, and they have not run into this issue.

Comment: boto2 has lots of monkey patch, Please create new virtualenv(s) and install both new and old boto2 version on each of these virtualenv and test again. If the new version breaks, please file a bug report to https://github.com/boto/boto/issues

Comment: I installed boto3 and it did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Please add an answer, say you install boto3 and modify the code, then tick accept answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mootmoot suggested, I installed boto3.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migration.html

boto3 works very differently from boto, so I had to make some changes to my code. The documentation can be found here.

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/